# Sets finding biggest value and minimum value using inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Consider the set A1, A2, A3 of | A1 | = 15, | A2 | = 12, | A3 | = 6, $| A1  \cap A2  \cap A3 | =3$ What is the minimum and maximum value of $|A1\cup  A2 \cup A3|$?

My attempt: the minimum value is 15
Because A1 is biggest set can contain 9 from A2 + 3 from A3 and 3 from $| A1  \cap A2 \cap A3 | =3$  so all satisfy

But for biggest possible value

$| A1 | + |A2 | + |A3 | - (|A1 \cup A2 | + |A2 \cup A3| + |A3 \cup A1) +3 $

Suppose a is $|A1 \cup A2 |$ and b= $|A2 \cup A3| $ and c= $|A3 \cup A1|$

$15+12+6-(a+b+c)+3=$

$a +b+c =36$

But we know also that

$a+b \leq 12$

$a+c \leq 9$

$b+c \leq 3$

Sum above $ 2a+2b+2c=24$

So $a+b+c=12$

Then how can i conclude what is the biggest value that is possible?

Consider the sets as people and there are 3 circle for every sets in venn diagram

Comment: $|A_1| \cup |A_2| \cup |A_3|$ doesn't make sense (you are forming the interesection of three numbers). Likewise for $|A_1| \cap |A_2| \cap |A_3|$. Can you check the statement of the problem and update your question please.

Comment: @RobArthan I dont know why it doesnt make sense(?) consider the sets as people, one person can be inside A1 or A2 and A3, and draw the venn diagram too, the intersection of A1 , A2,A3 is in the middle right?

Comment: It makes no sense because $|A_i|$ are not sets. They are numbers. Let $A_1=\{Tom, Dick, Harry\}$ and $A_2 = \{Tom, Jerry\}$ and $A_2=\{Tom, Harry, Holly, Fred\}$.  Well, then what can $3\cap 2 \cap 4$ mean?  And what can $3\cup 2 \cup 4$ mean.  They... literally.... do not make sense.

Comment: @fleablood consider like this, $A1=15$ for people who like baseball , $A2$ for people who like volley ball, $A3$ for people who like tennis, $|A1 \cap A2 \cap A3| $ who like tennis,baseball,volleyball . So inside A1 =15 there are people who like tennis baseball and volleyball

Comment: No.  Either $A_1$ is the set of people who like baseball and $|A_1|$ is the number of people who like baseball.  Of $A_1=15$.  $A_1$ can not be *both* the set and the number people in the set.  And no, there are no people in the number $15$.  If I gave you $15$ dollars you wont suddenly have a person who likes baseball, tennis, and volleyball in your pocket because there is such a person in a *set* with $15$ elements.  $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_|$ is the number of people who like all three.  But $|A_1|\cap |A_2|\cap |A_3|$ is nonsense that does not make any sense.

Comment: $X$ is a set; not a number.  And $|X|$ is a number, not a set-- the number it is, is the number of elements in the set.  You can intersect sets, so $X\cap Y$ makes sense.  And you can count the number of elements in the intersection, so $|X\cap Y|$ makes sense.  But you can not intersect *numbers* and $|X| \cap |Y|$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is incorrect.  You say, for example, that we know $a+b\leq12$ where $a=\mid A_1\cup A_2\mid$ and $b=\mid A_2\cup A_3\mid.$  On the contrary, since $\mid A_2\mid =12,$ we know $a+b\geq12$.

The only duplication required is that there are $3$ elements that belong to all $3$ sets.  Then just make all other elements distinct. For example, $A_1$ should have $12$ elements that belong to neither $A_2$ nor $A_3$.  You should find $27$ elements is the maximum.

Comment: Thankyou, do you got 27 because you set a,b,c=0? so |A1|=15-3=12 , |A2|=12-3=9,|A3|=6-3=3, so 12+3+9+3=27?

Comment: Well, I get $12+3+9+3=27$ as the answer.  I don't understand what $a,b,c$ are supposed to be.  If $a=\mid A_1\cup A_2\mid$ as you say, and $\mid A_1\mid=12$ then $a\geq12$, so setting $a=0$ makes no sense.